# A complete php project online debugger

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for an online service where I can host my entire php project which contains mySql, java scripts etc and yet be able to debug my php code line by line just like what I can do with Eclipse PDT (Zend Debuuger plugin, etc).

I am not looking for a pastebin like  mentioned here [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286199/an-online-php-debugger-code-editor), i am looking for a complete online debugging package so that we can complete the development all online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a server or VPS solution.  You can use xdebug, install whatever software you want, and use it the way you want.

Comment: yeah that as simple as you can get, also you have full control of everything, packages/extension/configurations, +1 from me

Comment: That's all true provided I have a dedicated server. With dedicated server I can do pretty much what I do right now on my desktop. I was looking for an online alternative ( except dedicated server)-Thanks

Comment: Which is why my answer clearly dictates a VPS, which is not a "dedicated" server.  Unless you're talking about just a PHP app host that allows debugging, and then the answer is, I don't know.